# How to send the parameter defined in the interceptor in the post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, axios

-> First of all I try to this in the axios request interceptor; if the parameter is **uber** then use token if the parameter is not uber I mean don't use token.

->After that how can I give **uber** as a parameter in the **customAxios** requsts in project file? When **customAxios** work in the project I want to set Authorization according to that uber parameter. Because some of my api requests,I do not need token and some of my api requests need token.If do you have an different idea,I can hear you

**my axios.ts file(configuration)**

```
let uber:any

const customAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: configEnv.apiBaseURL,
});

  customAxios.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      if (config.headers) {
        console.log('token', `Bearer ${token}`)
        config.headers['Authorization'] = uber ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
        return config;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
  )
```

**Sample axios post in a file;**

```
import customAxios from "../../../core/axios";

   let res = await customAxios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: "/v1/nodes",
                    data: {},
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can pass the `uber` parameter in the request's `config` object and set it to `true` or `false` depending on whether you need to use the token or not.

Here's how you can update your `customAxios` instance to get the `uber` parameter from the request's `config` object:

```js
const customAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: configEnv.apiBaseURL,
});

customAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (config.headers) {
      console.log('token', `Bearer ${token}`);
      const { uber } = config.params || {};
      config.headers['Authorization'] = uber ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
      return config;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

In your request, you can pass the `uber` parameter in the `config` object like this:

```js
let res = await customAxios({
  method: 'post',
  url: "/v1/nodes",
  data: {},
  params: {
    uber: true, // or false depending on your needs
  },
});
```

By doing this, the `customAxios` instance will use the `uber` parameter in the request's `config` object to determine whether to set the `Authorization` header or not. If the uber parameter is true, it will set the `Authorization` header with the token. Otherwise, it won't set the header.

Comment: if I don 't type params in the request,it will automatically will be false ,right?

Comment: It will be ‘undefined’ which is falsy. So yes, everything will work fine

Comment: why we need || {} usage . Could you explain me the logic  there.Code working good when I define const { uber } = config.params || {}.But if I define only define const { uber } = config.params getting error.Only want to learn logic

Comment: because `config.params` can be undefined. In this case destructuring assignment will throw an error, by adding `|| {}` you are telling js to get empty object if `config.params` are falsy.
Other way to deal with it is to use **optional chaining** eg `const uber = config.params?.uber`